# Why is github workflow always failing?

Tags: git, error-handling, yaml, github-actions, workflow

[image: Process of github workflow]

I've tried setting my local git repository's credentials from `08Miguel24` to `08Aristodemus24` which is my current username in by using both git config user.name and git config credentials.username, but to no avail it still gave me this workflow error.

I've also tried renaming my both my remote and local repository's branches to `main` since the workflow where this was gotten from was also named `main`, and still gave me this error.

The last thing I tried was making a fine grained personal access token for my github account since the workflow used it in the `profile-3d.yml` but yet again did it give me this error.

Here is the original workflow `profile-3d.yml` file where I got it from:

```
on:
  schedule: # 03:00 JST == 18:00 UTC
    - cron: "0 18 * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: generate-github-profile-3d-contrib
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: yoshi389111/github-profile-3d-contrib@0.7.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          USERNAME: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
      - name: Commit & Push
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add -A .
          git commit -m "generated"
          git push
```

And here is my current `.yml` file where the only thing I changed was the `cron` variable in order to run the workflow every hour:

```
on:
  schedule: # runs every hour
    - cron: "0 * * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: generate-github-profile-3d-contrib
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: yoshi389111/github-profile-3d-contrib@0.7.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          USERNAME: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
      - name: Commit & Push
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add -A .
          git commit -m "generated"
          git push
```

I'm also on windows so could it be that `ubuntu-latest` is playing a role here in giving me this error?

Comment: Status 403 is "unauthorized" - you've provided valid credentials, but the account associated with those credentials does not have permission to do what you're requesting. Did you maybe make the fine-grained permission too fine?